# How to add option to node shebang in the npm file?

Tags: node.js, npm

For testing i would like to add some option the

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

shebang in the /usr/bin/npm file

but :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --max_old_space_size=4096 --optimize_for_size --max_semi_space_size=4096 --stack_size=4096
```

is not working ...
It runs indefinitively even for a simple npm -v

any idea ?

regards

Comment: Do you invoke the file directly?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it's in /usr/bin so i run in my shell : ┌─[bussiere@batou] - [~/Workspace/finamaticD/finamatic/client] - [mar. août 01, 15:13]
└─[$] <git:(bussiere*)> npm -v 
5.3.0

Comment: How do you know the flags aren't working?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts when i run a npm -v it's not working it runs indefintiely

Comment: Please [edit] your question with whatever that is, I can't read that inline, and it's unclear what exactly is attempting to invoke `npm -v`. If you're doing that from within the node file, please provide the relevant code for that. If not, please clarify what you're trying to do, because that's also unclear.

Comment: "Works for me".